# How can I parse an object in a python c-extention?

Tags: python, c, parsing

I have in Python an object such as:

```
import test
class Test:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

t = Test(4)

test.c_function(t)
```

And I want to read it in c in the

```
static PyObject* py_c_function(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) {
  PyObject obj;
  if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &obj)) 
    return NULL;
  int n;
  
  // I want to access the the n member of the object or create a new Test struct
  return Py_BuildValue("i", n); 
  // or
  return Py_BuildValue("i", test.n);  

}
```

How can I access the members inside a pyObject for custom python data structures?

How can I do the opposite thing, assign values to an object that will later be called inside python?

**edit:**

As suggested by kpie, using the function PyObject_GetAttrString according to the documentation this should be equivalent to obj.n.

```
  PyObject * o = PyObject_GetAttrString(&obj, "n");
  
  long n;
  n = PyLong_AsLong(o);
```

But when I ran this I get the error:

```
SystemError: ../Objects/dictobject.c:1438: bad argument to internal function
```

**edit 2**

I am compiling the c code using GCC with:

```
 gcc -I/usr/include/python3.8/ -shared -o test.so -fPIC test.c
```

and then in the python script I add

```
import test
```

Comment: perhaps `PyObject_GenericGetAttr` will help? https://python.readthedocs.io/en/v2.7.2/c-api/object.html#PyObject_GenericGetAttr similarly `PyObject_GenericSetAttr` on the same page.

Comment: Thanks, That are the functions that I was looking but I am getting as error 
`SystemError: ../Objects/dictobject.c:1438: bad argument to internal function`
I will edit the question

Comment: How are you calling `c_function`? `ctypes` or custom extension? Show that code as well.

Comment: I updated the question in edit 2.
I compile a shared object using gcc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `PyObject_GetAttrString(obj,"attr")` can read the attributes of a python class similarly to obj.attr as commented by kpie.

The issue was `PyObject obj;` that was not a pointer.